# .Net ASMX client called remote service twice for every request

Tags: .net, asmx, basic-authentication

I have a web service hosted on remote AIX server, the service has HTTPS access and with basic authentication turned on.

I used ASMX Web References to generate the proxy classes from my .Net 4.0 project. So I have following codes to call to the web service

```
var service = new ServiceProxy();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("service-uid", "service-pwd");

var response = service.add(request);
```

That is very simple code. Now I ran Fiddler to inspect the traffic between my local Windows machine and remote Unix server, but I noticed following 4 lines from Fiddler:

- 200, HTTP, Tunnel To, unix-server-host
- 401, HTTPS, unix-server-host, /srvcs/method
- 200, HTTP, Tunnel To, unix-server-host
- 200, HTTPS, unix-server-host, /srvcs/method

I also opened my log file on AIX server, and confirmed 2 requests coming in within very close time

- source IP - unauthenticated 22/Aug/2013:14:05:51 -0500 "POST /srvcs/method HTTP/1.0" 401 1244
- source IP - service-uid 22/Aug/2013:14:05:52 -0500 "POST /srvcs/method HTTP/1.0" 200 3473

My service client issues 2 calls to Unix server, the first one is unauthenticated, the second one is successful - I got proper response.

Anybody understands why .Net client will generate first call without passing credential at all?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I know ASMX is legacy, but I truly believe there is some difference between ASMX generated proxy vs WCF generated proxy against Unix service (I think written in Java) in this very particular case. The WCF proxy is totally useless, the ASMX one still works.

Comment: Since WCF is intended by Microsoft to be a replacement for ASMX, if I were you, I'd make sure Microsoft knows about your use case where the WCF proxy is "useless".

Comment: I sure can send something to MS, but meanwhile I don't think I can wait unknown period of time to get support back, I have to deliver my project on time.

Comment: I'm not suggesting they'll fix it today - I'm suggesting you should give them a chance to fix it eventually, otherwise, you'll have the same complaint in 3 years.

Comment: Try to enable pre-authentication via the proxy class generated, and then user credentials should be sent in the first request.

Comment: @LexLi I eventually found the solution http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like that property is very misleading.